# Generated PDF is only downloading, not streaming in Laravel

Tags: laravel, pdf, stream

I am using the [barryvdh/laravel-dompdf](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf) package to generate PDFs. I want the PDF to be streamed in the browser. But according to this documentation, it is just downloading the PDF, not streaming in the browser. Is it possible to stream the PDF using this method?

**View**

```php
<a href="{{ route('admin.order.invoice', $order->id) }}" class="ml-2 btn btn-info">Generate Invoice</a>
```

**Route**

```php
Route::get('orders/invoice/{id}', 'Backend\OrdersController@generateInvoice')->name('admin.order.invoice');
```

**Controller**

```php
public function generateInvoice($id)
{
    $order = Order::find($id);
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('backend.pages.orders.invoice', compact('order'));

    return $pdf->stream('invoice.pdf');
}
```

Comment: just put return $pdf->stream();

Comment: It is resulting in the same thing.

Comment: Did you tried different browser? I used same as your code. it is worked for me

Comment: How did you use facade?

Comment: No..I only tried it in chrome. So, if it works in other browsers, why wouldn't it work for chrome?

Comment: check this https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/issues/7

Comment: In config/app.php, I used     Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class, as serviceprovider and  'PDF' => Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade::class,  as aliases.

Comment: I mean in the controller

Comment: In controller,  use PDF;

Comment: try this
use Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade as PDF;

Comment: Same as before...

Comment: hmm. I'm not sure. It should work on chrome. I did not face any issue. you can try clear cache.